# Weird results: matrix multiplication using pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads, matrix-multiplication

I made a program that multiplies matrices of the same dimension using (p)threads. The program accepts command line flags -N n -M m where n is the size of the matrix arrays and m is the number of threads (computing threshold). The program compiles and runs but I get strange times for elapsed time, USR time, SYS time, and USR+SYS time. I am testing sizes n = {1000,2000,4000} with each threshold m = {1,2,4}.

I should be seeing the elapsed time reduced and a fairly constant USR+SYS time for each value of n but that is not the case. The output will fluctuate but the problem is that a higher threshold doesn't result in a reduction of elapsed time. Am I implementing threads wrong or is there an issue with my timing?

compile with: -pthread

```
    ./* -N n -M m
```

**main**

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
    #include<pthread.h>
    #include<sys/time.h>
    #include<sys/resource.h>

    struct matrix {
        double **Matrix_A;
        double **Matrix_B;
        int begin;
        int end;
        int n;
    };

    void *calculon(void *mtrx) {
        struct matrix *f_mat = (struct matrix *)mtrx;
        // transfer data
        int f_begin = f_mat->begin;
        int f_end = f_mat->end;
        int f_n = f_mat->n;

        // definition of temp matrix
        double ** Matrix_C;
        Matrix_C = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double)*f_n);
        int f_pholder;
        for(f_pholder=0; f_pholder < f_n; f_pholder++)
            Matrix_C[f_pholder] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*f_n);

        int x, y, z;
        for(x = f_begin; x < f_end; x++) 
            for(y = 0; y < f_n; y++)
                for(z = 0; z < f_n; z++) 
                    Matrix_C[x][y] += f_mat->Matrix_A[x][z]*f_mat->Matrix_B[z][y];

        for(f_pholder = 0; f_pholder < f_n; f_pholder++)
            free(Matrix_C[f_pholder]);

        free(Matrix_C);
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        char *p;
        int c, i, j, x, y, n, m, pholder, n_m, make_thread;
        int m_begin = 0;
        int m_end = 0;

        while((c=getopt(argc, argv, "NM")) != -1) {
            switch(c) {
                case 'N':
                    n = strtol(argv[optind], &p, 10);
                    break;
                case 'M':
                    m = strtol(argv[optind], &p, 10);
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("\n**WARNING**\nUsage: -N n -M m");
                    break;
            }
        }
        if(m > n)
            printf("\n**WARNING**\nUsage: -N n -M m\n=> m > n");
        else if(n%m != 0)
            printf("\n**WARNING**\nUsage: -N n -M m\n=> n % m = 0");
        else {
            n_m = n/m;
            // initialize input matrices
            double ** thread_matrixA;
            double ** thread_matrixB;
            // allocate rows onto heap
            thread_matrixA=(double**)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
            thread_matrixB=(double**)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
            // allocate columns onto heap
            for(pholder = 0; pholder < n; pholder++) {
                thread_matrixA[pholder]=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
                thread_matrixB[pholder]=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
            }
            // populate input matrices with random numbers
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    thread_matrixA[i][j] = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX+1;

            for(x = 0; x < n; x++)
                for(y = 0; y < n; y++)
                    thread_matrixB[x][y] = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX+1;   

            printf("\n*** Matrix will be of size %d x %d *** \n", n, n);
            printf("*** Creating matrix with %d thread(s) ***\n", m);

            struct rusage r_usage;
            struct timeval usage;
            struct timeval time1, time2;
            struct timeval cpu_time1, cpu_time2;
            struct timeval sys_time1, sys_time2;
            struct matrix mat;

            pthread_t thread_lord[m];

            // begin timing
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &r_usage);
            cpu_time1 = r_usage.ru_utime;
            sys_time1 = r_usage.ru_stime;
            gettimeofday(&time1, NULL);

            for(make_thread = 0; make_thread < m; make_thread++) {
                m_begin += n_m;
                // assign values to struct
                mat.Matrix_A = thread_matrixA;
                mat.Matrix_B = thread_matrixB;
                mat.n = n;
                mat.begin = m_begin;
                mat.end = m_end;
                // create threads
                pthread_create(&thread_lord[make_thread], NULL, calculon, (void *)&mat);
                m_begin = (m_end + 1);
            }

            // wait for thread to finish before joining
            for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
                pthread_join(thread_lord[i], NULL);

            // end timing
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &r_usage);
            cpu_time2 = r_usage.ru_utime;
            sys_time2 = r_usage.ru_stime;
            gettimeofday(&time2, NULL);


            printf("\nUser time: %f seconds\n", ((cpu_time2.tv_sec * 1000000 + cpu_time2.tv_usec) - (cpu_time1.tv_sec * 1000000 + cpu_time1.tv_usec))/1e6);
            printf("System time: %f seconds\n", ((sys_time2.tv_sec * 1000000 + sys_time2.tv_usec) - (sys_time1.tv_sec * 1000000 + sys_time1.tv_usec))/1e6);
            printf("Wallclock time: %f seconds\n\n", ((time2.tv_sec * 1000000 + time2.tv_usec) - (time1.tv_sec * 1000000 + time1.tv_usec))/1e6);

            // deallocate matrices
            for(pholder = 0; pholder < n; pholder++) {
        free(thread_matrixA[pholder]);
        free(thread_matrixB[pholder]);
    }
    free(thread_matrixA);
    free(thread_matrixB);
}
return 0;
}
```

[Timing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcwPs.png)

Comment: what is the issue ? performance varies between runs ? first, make sure your results are correct, then bind your pthreads to cores. you might also consider using higher level abstraction model such as OpenMP.

Comment: You only have one 'mat', you are passing its address to all the threads while modifying it.  That won't end well.  malloc a separate mat for each thread, pass the address and free the mats at the end of the thread function.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that all those `malloc()`s you're using in the individual threads take a lot more time than you save by splitting the calculation among the threads. Math is fast; `malloc()` is slow. (To oversimplify a bit)

Sometimes weird timing behavior with threads happens when you have multiple threads trying to access a shared resource which is protected by some kind of exclusive lock. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612860/what-can-make-a-program-run-slower-when-using-more-threads), from something I did a long time ago) But I don't think that's the case here because, first of all, you don't seem to be using any locks, and second, the timing pattern that results typically has the runtime increasing by a little bit as you increase the number of threads. In this case, your runtime increases as you increase the number of threads, by a *lot* (specifically: it seems to be related to the thread number), so I suspect per-thread resource usage to be the culprit.

That being said, I'm having a hard time confirming my guess, so I can't be sure about this.